# Already installed lxml but still have "ImportError: lxml not found, please install it" error

Tags: python, lxml

I have already installed lxml using `pip install lxml`, I even used `pip list` to check and found that lxml is indeed there. 
I even uninstall and installed lxml again but this `"ImportError: lxml not found, please install it"` is still there.

I'm intended to use read_html() to convert html table to panda data frame. 
This is my code:

```
import html5lib
url = 'https://www.crunchbase.com/search/funding_rounds/field/organizations/funding_total/nobroker'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
```

And I'm always getting `"ImportError: lxml not found, please install it"`, may I know how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you installed it for Python 2 and attempted to import it in Python 3?

Comment: if you have two pythons and you use `python3` to run code then you should have `pip3` to install modules. Or you can use `python3 -m pip install lxml`

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing a new package directly in PyCharm and it worked for me.

Settings->Project->Project Interpreter.

This will show you the details of the interpreter that runs your project.
lxml should be in the package's table. If not there you can press the plus icon in the right corner of the window and type lxml and proceed with the installation.